# can php limit actions based on ip address

Tags: php, limit

i have 2 links that display notifications on my website and its being abused. is there a way to limit the amount of times a user can click the links based on ip address i dont want to block anyone i just want to reduce the amount of times a person can click this link. essentially limiting the requests that can be made

Answer (score 4):

Definitely, on the pre-set variables (I think $_SERVER array, REMOTE_ADDR) you can see:

> The IP address from which the user is viewing the current page.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes, implement a simple IP filter using $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"])

confer http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.predefined.php

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not a good idea to rely on the client IP address because of proxies and VPN's that can mask the true value.  It would be better to set a cookie and keep track of the clicks in this manner.

Comment: there are also as many arguments in favor of ip blocking. in this particular case i think ip blocking makes more sense because a user can delete or not use cookies any time. and since this is a deliberate action of abusing his service, this is easier than using proxies/vpns to get hold of multiple ip adresses.

Comment: do you have any ideas on how i can do this or information i can google?

Comment: There are some examples of setting cookie values in the PHP documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php